# Get undefined when trying to access object in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

inside es6 class constructor i call a function that returns successfully an array of two objects

But, when i try to access one of those objects i get undefined

here is the log ...

---

console.log(images) gives

Array []
​
0: Object { _id: 118, index: 0, _batchingTransformChange: false, … }
​
1: Object { _id: 130, index: 0, _batchingTransformChange: false, … }
​
length: 2
​
: Array []

---

And console.log(images[0])

images[0]  undefined

constructor code

```
constructor(snapWidth, blockPositioning, config = {}) {

    if (!Object.values(BlockPositioning).includes(blockPositioning)) {
        throw 'Parameter blockPositioning is not supported!';
    }

    super(config)

    this.#snapWidth = snapWidth

    this.somevalue = 7

    this.#blockPositioning = blockPositioning

    let images = this.#addActionImages()

    this.addActionImg = images[0]
    this.removeActionImg = images[1]

    console.log('images ', images)

    console.log('images[0] ', images[0])
    console.log('images[1] ', images[1])

    console.log('this.addActionImg ', this.addActionImg)
    console.log('this.removeActionImg ', this.removeActionImg)
}
```

Comment: @Strazan no bro i think it s something js related, btw am using firefox

Comment: Can you provide more context, so that I can reproduce? :D

Comment: I can't just run this code to reproduce, you'll have to give me more